# How to automatic build a "lite" version

Tags: android, android-build, android-drawable

I have made an app that has got a lot of graphics for a miriad of different buttons. All the graphic for each and every button is replicated scaled in `drawable-xhdpi`, `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-mdpi` and `drawable-ldpi`.

The amount of graphics in the first two directories is around 3.5MB, while the app in its all is about 7.5MB.

Obviously it would crazy to ask people that own low-end smartphones to download and fill their memory with 3.5MB of graphics that are completely useless, so I decided to make one "`lite`" version for such people.

I want to have a constant, something like

```
  static final boolean LITE_BUILD = true;
```

So that when I set it to true, the build automatically excludes `xhdpi` and `hdpi` graphics.

Right now the only solution I have is to manually move away those two directories, build the lite version, put the directories back and build the complete version. obviously it's not optimal.

Comment: Question is good, however people in most cases won't care about extra size. Just let them download

Comment: Bojan is right, most people with not having the luxury of storage will buy a sd-card to expand there size.

Comment: In my opinion that's nonsense. Yes, there are huge amounts of storage space available - nevertheless some people have only low download bandwidth and therfore DO care about the size of an app. Beside of that: many developes that think this way will create lousy and poor apps that are slow and huge because they added some cool frameworks/libraries just to get some poor functionality while most parts of the framework are unused. So it is a question of code quality too...

Comment: I use a Nexus 4 for development and my space is rammed. I can't add an SD card to it. And in any case it's BS to say that people won't care about the size. It's definitely a reasonable question. If I downloaded it and saw that it was that size it would be removed in minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Since all the drawables you put in these folders are constant, I think building the same  app twice, while in the lite version it has only the low dpi images, will be the only solution.

if you are worried about people downloading the right app(full or lite) for their phone, you can flag in the app manfiest what phone screen sizes it supports.

so low dpi phones will only see the lite version while other phones will see the full version ( I think it works this way ).

Comment: This is a good idea. In this way I would not even have to worry about saying that it is a "lite" version and change the icon.
As you know, does google play support this automatically? I mean, I could have the same single page for the app, and multiple .apks... I think it could work automatically, I'll have a test try soon.

Comment: I, Myself never actually tried it, but i think it is possible

Answer (score 2):

Are you building your app on Linux? Here you could create several variants of your project directory while setting symlinks to the directories you need - and leaving out the directories with the high resolution images for the low res variant of the app. This way you can work using one code base while creation of several variants of your app is quite easy.

Comment: No sorry, Windows XP vm + eclipse... Maybe in eclipse itself is possible to set different build configurations?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a sane version control system, right? Then add different branches in your vcs for different resolution builds.

Do the common features in a common base branch(trunk/master?) and merge those changes to the separate resolution branches. Add the resolution depended drawables only to the branch in question as well as the modifications to the manifest.

Now, when you want to build a version for, say ldpi, change to the lpdi branch, make sure the changes to the base branch are merged and build the apk normally. Voila, you have a lpdi-build.

Comment: No I actually don't use any vcs... I just use eclipse, but no version history management. Unless eclipse makes it silently for me in the background... that could be possible seen how powerful that ide is.

Comment: No version of eclipse I have ever used has done any kind of version control unless configured. If not using vcs, I hope you are at least continuously taking backups of your code(and have backed up your publish keys). Disaster prevention is way cheaper than disaster recovery.